# Python print end="\r" previous line not completely cleared

Tags: python

I want to replace current line in console

```
from time import sleep

print("loooooooooooooooooooog", end="\r")
sleep(1)
print("short", end="\r")
```

output

```
shortoooooooooooooooog
```

expected

```
short
```

Comment: Because `\r` just goes to the beginning of the line. It doesn't clear the line. More at e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

Comment: There's an escape sequence that will clear the current line. Use that after `\r`.

Comment: @Barmar `sys.stdout.write('\033[K .... \r')` ?

Comment: No need to use `sys.stdout`, you can do it with `print()`

Comment: using `print()` not work on windows

Comment: It works perfectly fine on Windows.  Are you running it inside an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

for linux we can do

```
sys.stdout.write('\033[K Text \r')
# or
print('\033[K Text \r')
```

but it has strange result on windows powershell or cmd, so I use this function instead

```
from time import sleep

prevline = 0

def writeLine(text):
    global prevline
    current = len(text)
    if current > prevline:
        prevline = current
    print(text.ljust(prevline), end="\r")

writeLine('looooooooooooong')
sleep(1)
writeLine('short')
sleep(1)
writeLine('s')
```

Comment: The `print` statement works perfectly fine on Windows.  I just tried your exact code.  Are you running inside an IDE?

Comment: @TimRoberts you mean `print("\033[KText \r")` ?  it print  `←[KText` on PS, CMD also it not replace prev line

Comment: It works fine in CMD for me.  I didn't try PowerShell.  It doesn't REPLACE the previous line, but if the previous line ended with `\r` instead of `\n`, it does erase it.  That's what it's supposed to do.